# Combining List and Form views in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, user-interface, swiftui

I there anyway to combine a List and say Form view on the same screen? or do you have to have one or the other and manually build the rest?

I have this code, and each component the list and the form, are scrolling independently and also very spaced apart..

[image]

```
var body: some View {
        
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Form {
                    Text(orgEntity.name)
                    Text(orgEntity.address)
                }
                .padding([.bottom], 20)
                List {
                    ForEach(0...3, id: \.self ) { int in
                        Text("List Test \(int)")
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("\(orgEntity.name)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use list: place everything in the `Form` with `Section`s, like this:

```
var body: some View {
            
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Text("Name")
                    Text("Address")
                }
                Section {
                    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self ) { int in
                        Text("List Test \(int)")
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.bottom], 20)
            .navigationTitle("\("Name")")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the stationary form and still have a scrolling list then  a frame(height:) can be used on the Form:

```
.frame(height: 80)
```

Result:

[image]

Example code:

```
struct ComboView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Form {
                Text("Name O")
                Text("O Michigan St.")
            }
            .frame(height: 80)
            
            List {
                ForEach(0...20, id: \.self ) { int in
                    Text("List Test \(int)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Name O")
        }
    }
}
```